# SpriteKit animation issue Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, sprite-kit

I am having trouble with my animation in swift. The animation is not playing.

These are my swift files:

This is my sprite file:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Dog: SKSpriteNode {

var dog = SKSpriteNode()

var textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas()
var textureArray = [SKTexture]()

init() {
    super.init(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed:"dog_1"), color: UIColor.clear, size: CGSize(width: 44, height: 25))
    textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "dog")

    for i in 1...textureAtlas.textureNames.count {

        let name = "dog_\(i).png"
        textureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: name))

    }

}

func animate() {
    dog.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: textureArray, timePerFrame: 0.1)))
}

func stopAnimation() {
    dog.removeAllActions()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

This is my GameScene file:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var dog: Dog!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 132.0/255.0, green: 179.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    addDog()

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    dog.animate()
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    dog.stopAnimation()
}

func addDog() {

    dog = Dog()
    dog.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
    addChild(dog)
}

}
```

I think the problem is in the animate function in the sprite file.

I have tried everything I can think of. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See if for loop is even executed. Put a breakpoint in it ... Also, remove the .png extension from the image name - `let name = "dog_\(i)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your class **Dog** you have a var **dog** that is initialised as an SKSpriteNode. Your start and stop animate functions then operate on that **dog**, not the class itself and not the other **dog** in your game scene. As that **dog** is never added to the scene your animation is never visible.

Remove the dog var and references to it from Dog - the animations should be running on your subclass Dog directly.

Comment: Oh yeah. Instance var dog from class Dog is never added to a node tree... Nicely spoted :)